# The problem of formatting text pick up textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea

I can't put the code below into "textarea" because of a line break (enter):

1) install

2) Ok

3) Like

It works if I write this without breaking the line:

1) install 2) Ok 3) Like

Is there any way to put the code into textarea without interfering with the code? The above code is fixed from the database (BBcode).

**html**

```
<textarea class="message" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
```

**javascript**

```
$('.message').html('1) install
2) Ok
3) Like');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v9kpdn4t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `val()` not `html()` for `<textarea>`

```js
const str=`1) install

2) Ok

3) Like

html`

$('.message').val(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="message" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
```

Comment: Yes! It works but when I apply it to the xenforo editor, it doesn't break the line? can you show me how to fix
https://i.imgur.com/zauOOaP.png

Comment: That appears to be an html editor. Parse the string and replace line breaks with `<br>` to create html line breaks

Comment: very easy to search for

Comment: You mean to write <br> to break the line? But I do not want to edit the text. How do I not edit the text but still break the line?

Comment: That is how html works. It doesn't honor `\n` line breaks and uses `<br>` instead

Comment: I found a way to automatically add <br> to the code. You answered my question correctly. Thank you

Comment: $('.message').val(str.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br />').replace(/[\r\n]/g, '<br />'));